Mutiny Uni: Is it thread-safe to modify a final object within onItem and onFailure handlers?
final MyObject myObj = new MyObject("initial value");

myUni
    .subscribe().with(
        result -> { 
            // Success handler
            myObj.setValue(result + " processed"); 
        },
        failure -> { 
            // Failure handler
            myObj.setValue("failed: " + failure.getMessage()); 
        }
    );

Is this approach thread-safe?  Could there be any race conditions if myObj is accessed or modified by other parts of the application concurrently?

This itself is perfectly fine and thread-safe. If, however, you'll have other threads accessing (or even modifying) the same myObj instance, you'll have to employ the classic thread-safety measures (such as locks or lock-free programming).
